# Linked list c++ insertback

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am really new to data structures. I am trying to figure out why my `insertback()` function doesn't work. The first print does `3,2,1` but the second doesn't print anything. I think it has something to do with `head`, but I'm not really sure. Please help.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

class lst
{
public:
    void Insertfron(int x);
    void Print();
    void Insertback(int x);
private:
    Node* head;
};

void lst::Insertfron(int x)
{
    Node* temp = new Node;
    temp->data = x;
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
}

void lst::Print()
{
    Node* temp = head;
    while(temp->next!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<temp->data<<' ';
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    cout<< endl;
}

void lst::Insertback(int x)
{
    Node* backinst = new Node;
    backinst->data = x;
    backinst->next = NULL;
    Node* temp = head;
    while(temp->next!=NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->next = backinst;
}

int main()
{
    lst listt;
    listt.Insertfron(1);
    listt.Insertfron(2);
    listt.Insertfron(3);
    listt.Print();
    listt.Insertback(4);
    listt.Print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `lst listt;` -- after this line executes, and this object gets constructed, can you explain what you expect to be `listt.head`, exactly why it should be what you think it is, and how the rest of the program should work because of that? Since this is the very first line of the program, it should be possible to answer this very easily.

Comment: I don't see `head` initialized anywhere.  As a result, the behavior can be undefined.  `head` might be non-NULL.  This is a very short program that you can debug easily, especially since you seem to have isolated the issue to one function.  Try adding output statements in your loop to see how many times it runs.

Comment: isn't head the pointer to the first node of the list

Comment: No, it's not. Why do you think it is? The `head` is going to be whatever the program makes it to be, so, what does the completely new `lst`'s `head` will be, or you think should be, and why? Just because some pointer happens to be called `head`, that by itself doesn't make anything happen. It's just the name of some pointer. What it is, and how it works, is completely up to the program's logic, and correct logic needs to be implemented to make it do what it should do. This logic is completely missing from the shown code.

Comment: @krisegotin "*isn't head the pointer to the first node of the list*" - that is its *purpose*, yes.  But you are not *initializing* it, so none of the methods called on the `listt` object know that the list is actually empty once `listt` has been constructed. Yu need to add a constructor to `lst` to initialize `head` to `NULL`.

Comment: So I initialized `head` to NULL and also found another mistake in `Print()` where the loop condition should be `temp!=NULL` instead of `temp->next!=NULL`. Now it works fine Thank you.

Comment: @krisegotin "*found another mistake in `Print()`*" - `Insertback()` also has a similar bug. When the list is empty, where `head` is `NULL`, so `while (temp->next!=NULL)` is invalid.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for pointing that out.  I just didn't bother checking if the list is empty since I knew it wasn't in that case. Right now I'm just testing stuff,  but thanks a lot for the reminder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not initializing `head` to `NULL` to indicate an empty list, so ``head` will have a random garbage value, and thus all of your methods exhibit **undefined behavior**.

Once that is fixed, your `while` loops in both `Print()` and `Insertback()` are buggy, as they are not account for `head` being `NULL` when the list is empty.

Also, you are leaking every node you create.  You need to add a destructor to free the nodes when you are done using the list.

With that said, try something more like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

class lst
{
public:
    lst();
    ~lst();
    void Insertfron(int x);
    void Print();
    void Insertback(int x);
private:
    Node* head;
};

lst::lst()
    : head(NULL)
{
}

lst::~lst()
{
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        Node *next = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = next;
    }
}

void lst::Insertfron(int x)
{
    Node* temp = new Node;
    temp->data = x;
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
}

void lst::Print()
{
    Node* temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        cout << temp->data << ' ';
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void lst::Insertback(int x)
{
    Node* backinst = new Node;
    backinst->data = x;
    backinst->next = NULL;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = backinst;
    }
    else
    {
        Node* temp = head;
        while (temp->next != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = backinst;
    }
}

int main()
{
    lst listt;
    listt.Insertfron(1);
    listt.Insertfron(2);
    listt.Insertfron(3);
    listt.Print();
    listt.Insertback(4);
    listt.Print();
    return 0;
}
```

That being said, `Insertback()` can be simplified to avoid the extra `if` by using an extra level of pointer indirection:

```
void lst::Insertback(int x)
{
    Node **temp = &head;
    while (*temp != NULL)
    {
        temp = &((*temp)->next);
    }
    Node* backinst = new Node;
    backinst->data = x;
    backinst->next = NULL;
    *temp = backinst;
}
```